# C++ Circular Declaration Issues

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I am having an issue with circular declarations but so far all the solutions found do not solve the issue directly.

Here is some code:

**Transformable.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "TransformMatrix.h"

class Transformable {
public:
    TransformMatrix Transform;
    virtual void transform_callback();
};
```

**TransformMatrix.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "Transformable.h"

class Transformable;

class TransformMatrix {

private:

    Transformable *callback_object;

public:

    TransformMatrix();

    TransformMatrix(Transformable *cb_object);
```

**Transforms.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Transformable.h"
#include "TransformMatrix.h"
```

**A.h**

```
class A: public Transformable {
public:
    A();

    /* We want a callback */
    TransformMatrix Transform = TransformMatrix(this);
```

I have a class that implements the base class, and uses a special header so I don't have to include two files each time. But the error I get is:

> Transformable.h(7): error C3646: 'Transform': unknown override
>   Transformable.h(7): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int.

Comment: You should remove the #include "Transformable.h" directive from your TransformMatrix.h file.

Comment: I tried that also, I end up getting:
`1>TransformMatrix.cpp(141): error C2027: use of undefined type 'Transformable'
1>TransformMatrix.h(8): note: see declaration of 'Transformable'
1>TransformMatrix.cpp(141): error C2227: left of '->transform_callback' must point to class/struct/union/generic type`

Comment: Sounds like you now need to add a #include "Transformable.h" into your TransformMatrix.cpp file?

Comment: Add `#include "Transformable.h"` in TransformMatrix.cpp.

Comment: Alright, that fixed it, but I also had to change the virtual void in Transformable.h to a regular void, because even though I am using a type cast, the compiler doesn't know that the cast hasn't been implemented.
Thanks!

Comment: For next project, try Golang ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that *TransformMatrix.h* can treat `Transformable` as an opaque type, then you can simply use the existing forward declaration, and remove the `#include Transformable.h` from *TransformMatrix.h*. The implementation file for `TransformMatrix` may then need `#include Transformable.h` to be added. (This is gathered from the comments below your question.)

However, it may be the case that such knowledge is needed. Then, we consider that there is a design flaw in your class dependencies, and we attempt to correct it.

We notice that `Transformable` has a virtual method, yet also wants to contain a `TransformMatrix`. Likely, we can correct your issue by removing this dependency. At this point, it would be guess work since you do not show enough code to completely understand your intended design.

But, if I were to attempt to maintain your existing design as closely as possible, I would convert `TransformMatrix` into a template, and abstract away `Transformable` into a template parameter.

```
#pragma once

template <typename T>
class TransformMatrixTemplate {
private:

    T *callback_object;

public:

    TransformMatrixTemplate();

    TransformMatrixTemplate(T *cb_object);
```

Then, `typedef` the template using `Transformable` in *Transforms.h*.

```
#pragma once
#include "Transformable.h"
#include "TransformMatrix.h"

typedef TransformMatrixTemplate<Transformable> TransformMatrix;
```